# ERROR : ResourcesNotFoundException during activity layout inflation

Tags: android

i'm trying to make calculator which contains two edit text for input and one textview 
and four buttons for add ,sub,multiply, divide
while building it shows the error's

i'm unable to figure out the problem kindly help

ERROR

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.Main`enter code here`Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class ImageView

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: 

    Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 

    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class 
    ImageView

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 



Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f06005f
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML   FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/calculator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCalculator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="Calculator"
        android:textColor="#F5F34336"
        android:textColorLink="#05C2DA"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumberFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter First Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumberSecond"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Second Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E9E65183"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textColorHighlight="#2A94A1"
        android:textColorLink="#00BCD4"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#EDDF635B"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/subtract"
        android:textColorLink="#00BCD4"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiplication"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E9E65183"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/multiplication"
        android:textColorLink="#00BCD4"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#EDDF635B"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/divide"
        android:textColorLink="#00BCD4"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA   FILE

```
package com.example.calculator;    
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText textNumberFirst, textNumberSecond;
    TextView txtResult, textCalculator;
    Button add,subtract,multiplication,divide;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textNumberFirst=findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberFirst);
        textNumberSecond=findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberSecond);

        txtResult=findViewById(R.id.textResult);

        add=findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        subtract=findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtract);
        multiplication=findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiplication);
        divide=findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int firstNumber, secondNumber, result;
                firstNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberFirst.getText().toString());
                secondNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberSecond.getText().toString());
                result=firstNumber+secondNumber;
                txtResult.setText(result);
            }
        });

        subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int firstNumber,secondNumber,result;
                firstNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberFirst.getText().toString());
                secondNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberSecond.getText().toString());
                result=firstNumber+secondNumber;
                txtResult.setText(result);
            }
        });

        multiplication.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int firstNumber,secondNumber,result;
                firstNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberFirst.getText().toString());
                secondNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberSecond.getText().toString());
                result=firstNumber+secondNumber;
                txtResult.setText(result);
            }
        }));

        divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int firstNumber,secondNumber,result;
                firstNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberFirst.getText().toString());
                secondNumber=Integer.parseInt(textNumberSecond.getText().toString());
                result=firstNumber/secondNumber;
                txtResult.setText(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.calculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException - probably the @drawable/calculator is not found

Comment: Remove the @drawable/calculator file from the project and add it again and build the app if still shows the same error close and open the Android studio again it might help.